How do I tell that the new inspector window was the result of a user clicking Reply or Forward button using Office JS in Outlook?
In Outlook COM Add-ins, we can catch the Reply/Forward events but for Web/JS Add-ins, there doesn't seem to be such events exposed. The closest one is OnNewMessageCompose and OnMessageCompose but AFAIK, the event object that is passed when this event is raised do not contain properties that indicate whether it is a Reply/Forward or not.
The Office.context.mailbox.item also do not seem to expose any such properties.
Or is there any "out-of-the-box" ideas that I should look at? The goal is for the plugin to identify whether the New Email window/dialog was the result of a Reply/Forward action in Outlook.

Starting from API set 1.10 there is an exposed function on the mailbox item Office.context.mailbox.item.getComposeTypeAsync() which specifies the type of message compose and its coercion type. The message can be new, or a reply or forward. See Office.MailboxEnums.ComposeType for an example and enumeration values.
